# How to clear Console Logs in Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Is there any way to clear the logs written by the application in Azure Mobiles Services by

```
console.log()
console.error()
...
```

I would be interested in a procedure either with code or through Management portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the logs cannot be cleared - they're automatically removed after 7 days. You can create a new feature request in the [UserVoice page](https://mobileservices.uservoice.com/forums/182281-feature-requests) if you feel this is important for you.

Comment: Glad to hear they are removed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can now. Connect to the WAMS kudu endpoint:

`https://<yourservicename>.**scm**.azure-mobile.net` 
(notice, this isn't your public endpoint of the service)

and use the cmd console to navigate to D:\Home\Logfiles\Application and enter del *.txt in the console.

Comment: This is the real correct answer. This works really well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way
In Visual Studio 2012 I connected to Azure account then in Server Explorer I selected the WADLogsTable
Then viewing the contents I selected and deleted from the pop-up menu choose